# How to download big files with php?

Tags: php, file, video, memory, download

I am trying to download 280 MB video file from server but it says that out of memory and even if I increase memory limit it doesn't worked.But I suprised that I am able to download this file from video element download button,when I click it it wait about 1 minute then download begin,but with a php it doesn't worked

```
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"{$file_viewname}{$file_extension}\"");
    readfile($file_path);
```

I want to learn that why video tag download worked?how can I force video element download file without whow it to user?And most important how can I download this throught from php

Comment: that looks more like upload than download. unless $file_path is a remote server?

Comment: @nogad yes $file_path came from server

Comment: Remote or local

Comment: @nogad it is local file,problem is memory problem even I increased memory limit it gave me below:`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1048576) (tried to allocate 280469504 bytes) in ...`.And if user clicked download button of video tag , it works but I want to force user download without opening video with video tag